# Share a class instance between activities

Tags: android, android-activity, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm freshman regarding to Android dev and I don't really understand everything about this language. Here is my question.

I would like to create a class allowing me to handle a Bluetooth communication. This class should be able to give me a list of the nearly devices, to connect to one, send and receive informations to and from some characteristics...

So, as I need only one connexion for the application, I need the instance of this class to be common to differents activities. And here is the problem! I don't really know how to pass this instance through these activities. I've heard about Intent, but it's seems to be usefull only to pass common types. I've thought about static class and methods but I'm not sure that's a good way...

So I would be glad if someone could give me a way to do this.

Thanks in advance! :)

Harold.

Comment: Android is an Operating System. Not a programming language.

Comment: @blackbelt I think he is talking about Android development. Not OS.

Comment: To the extent I know you may need to use `Singleton` class

Comment: If you're new, and going straight to advanced stuff, you're going to hear(read) a lot of mumbo jumbo. Android has very good API reference, but, of course, it's too difficult for novice users. I spent about 1 month on tutorials, until I could refer to Docs, so I suggest you do the same. If you're not familiar to Java, you should spend at least one month on Java, before going to Android.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. Using a Singleton class partialy resolved my problem. I also implemented the MVC model to really separate displaying and Bluetooth communication using this link: [link](http://baptiste-wicht.developpez.com/tutoriels/conception/mvc/) (sorry for the non-French-speaking people...)
@Marius: I would be happy to take one month to learn to develop with Android but I need to have finish my little application in a few weeks! :p

Comment: @Blackbelt If you want to talk about the programming language, what do you say? Java?? Java is not Android specific, Android Java is a different thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your class don't rely on Activity lifecycle, use [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) pattern :

```
public class YourClass
{
    private static YourClass mInstance;
    protected YourClass(){}

    public static YourClass getInstance()
    {
         if(mInstance == null)
              mIntance = new YourClass();
    return mIntance;
    }
}
```